# Html email body not being rendered correctly

Tags: c#, html, css

I am trying to send an email with images embedded in the body. I have provided js fiddle of what the html looks like which is generated by the C# code. I have used a updated `src` in the js fiddle so the images get displayed. The js fiddle can be accessed **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/o5dyoqrx/341/)**

The emails get sent correctly with the image embedded in the body. My issue is with the styling of the divs which are not aligned when I view them in outlook. For that I have provided a screenshot below:

[image]

As you can see in the screen shot the divs are stacked where as in the js fiddle they are aligned. Can someone tell me where I am going wrong please. Below is my code.

```
MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
message.To.Add(new MailAddress("to"));
message.From = new MailAddress("from");
LinkedResource res = new LinkedResource(@"C:\TestFolder\TestImage.jpg");
message.Subject = "Test Email";
message.IsBodyHtml = true;

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append("<html>");
sb.Append("<body>");
sb.Append("<div style=\"display: flex; justify-content: space-between;\">");
sb.Append("<div style=\"width: auto; height: 100px;\">");
sb.Append("<img style=\"height: 100px;\" src='cid:" + res.ContentId + @"'/>");
sb.Append("</div>");
sb.Append("<div style=\"width: auto; height: 100px;\">");
sb.Append("<h1>Hello World</h1>");
sb.Append("</div>");
sb.Append("<div style=\"width: auto; height: 100px;\">");
sb.Append("<img style=\"height: 100px;\" src='cid:" + res.ContentId + @"'/>");
sb.Append("</div>");
sb.Append("</div>");
sb.Append("</body>");
sb.Append("</html>");

AlternateView alternateView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(sb.ToString(), null, MediaTypeNames.Text.Html);
alternateView.LinkedResources.Add(res);
message.AlternateViews.Add(alternateView);

using (var smtp = new SmtpClient())
{
   var credential = new NetworkCredential
   {
      UserName = "email", 
      Password = "password"
   };
   smtp.Credentials = credential;
   smtp.Host = "host";
   smtp.Port = 587;
   smtp.Send(message);
}
```

Finally if I do the `sb.ToString()` produces the following html string.

```html
<div style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between;">
  <div style="width: auto; height: 100px;">
    <img style="height: 100px;" src="http://d3sdoylwcs36el.cloudfront.net/VEN-virtual-enterprise-network-business-opportunities-small-fish_id799929_size485.jpg">
  </div>
  <div style="width: auto; height: 100px;">
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
  </div>
  <div style="width: auto; height: 100px;">
    <img style="height: 100px;" src="http://d3sdoylwcs36el.cloudfront.net/VEN-virtual-enterprise-network-business-opportunities-small-fish_id799929_size485.jpg">
  </div>
```

Comment: For outlook you can use `table`. `div` not working correctly and `display:flex` also not supported.

Comment: Flex is not supported in outlook. See https://litmus.com/community/discussions/1500-using-flexbox-in-an-email for justification

Comment: @ankitapatel Thanks, I did not know that!

Comment: @Adriani6 Thanks for the link I will have a look

Comment: @Izzy Unfortunately emails just don't really support CSS properly (though that is changing). Here's a list of things that will work; https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Answer (score 0):

```
    <div style="width: auto; height: 100px;display:table;width:150px;float:left">
        <img style="height: 100px;" src='http://d3sdoylwcs36el.cloudfront.net/VEN-virtual-enterprise-network-business-opportunities-small-fish_id799929_size485.jpg' />
    </div>
    <div style="width: auto; display:table;width:400px;float:left;text-align:center;">
        <h1>
            Hello World</h1>
    </div>
    <div style="width: auto; height: 100px;display:table;width:150px;float:left;text-align:right;">
        <img style="height: 100px;" src='http://d3sdoylwcs36el.cloudfront.net/VEN-virtual-enterprise-network-business-opportunities-small-fish_id799929_size485.jpg' />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's better that you explain something, then share code

Comment: outlook email does't  support flex and some of the css you have used. at here we have to provide fix width using display table to achieve the output you required.

Comment: please check this code in any email template and verify the same. it's working perfect.